# Magento 1.8 - Ways to speed up this code?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, javascript, css

How can i speed up the code inside my cms homepage?

A few questions i have:

1) The code for the homepage slider is causing 5 http image requests...is there a way to reduce this and keep 5 banners?

2) Does everything need the https:// on the front or can i use relative urls.

Here is all the code.

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0 -10px;">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0 10px;">
        <div class="home-side-menu" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <h2 class="side-menu-title">CATEGORIES</h2>
            {{block type="core/template" template="smartwave/megamenu/html/sidemenu.phtml"}}
            {{block type="core/template" template="smartwave/megamenu/html/sidemobilemenu.phtml"}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="padding:0 10px;">
        <div class="owl-bottom-narrow owl-banner-carousel" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div id="banner-slider-demo-6" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/low-cost-print.png"}}" alt="Save Money On Print" width="700" height="306" />
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/free-uk-delivery.png"}}" alt="Free UK Delivery" width="700" height="306" />
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/follow-social-media.png"}}" alt="Follow NextLevelPrint1 on Social Media" width="700" height="306" />
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/expert-print-advice.png"}}" alt="Quality Customer Service" width="700" height="306" />
                </div>                
                <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/high-quality-print.png"}}" alt="High Quality Print Products" width="700" height="306" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){
                $("#banner-slider-demo-6").owlCarousel({autoPlay:true,lazyLoad: true,stopOnHover: true,pagination: true, autoPlay: true,navigation: false,slideSpeed : 500,paginationSpeed : 500,singleItem:true});
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin:0 -10px;">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0 10px;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#image-slider-demo-6").owlCarousel({
                lazyLoad: true,
                navigation : false,
                slideSpeed : 300,
                paginationSpeed : 400,
                singleItem:true
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div class="block block-subscribe home-sidebar-block" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:30px;">
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span>Be the First to Know</span></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <p>Keep up to date on the latest news of our products and special offers.<br />Enter your e-mail and subscribe to our newsletter.</p>
                {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/home_side_subscribe.phtml"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="filter-title" style="background-image:none;margin-bottom:5px;"><span class="content"><strong>Testimonials</strong></span></h2>
        <div id="testimonials-slider-demo-6" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <blockquote class="testimonial">
                    <p>Professional &amp; very competitively priced. I speak very highly of your services to all of my business associates &amp; always recommend you.</p>
                </blockquote>
                <div class="testimonial-arrow-down"></div>
                <div class="testimonial-author">
                    <div class="img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-small"><img width="60" height="60" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/07/client-1-11.jpg"}}" alt="Client Recommendation 1"/></div>
                    <p><strong>Gary Shepherd</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <blockquote class="testimonial">
                    <p>Thank you for the amazing service &amp; super quick delivery. We weren't expecting such a fast turn-around but we were pleasantly surprised.</p>
                </blockquote>
                <div class="testimonial-arrow-down"></div>
                <div class="testimonial-author">
                    <div class="img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-small"><img width="60" height="60" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/07/client-1-12.jpg"}}" alt="Client Recommendation 2"/></div>
                    <p><strong>John Andrews</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#testimonials-slider-demo-6").owlCarousel({
                lazyLoad: true,
                responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
                slideSpeed: 200,
                paginationSpeed: 500,
                scrollPerPage: true,
                stopOnHover: true,
                rewindNav: true,
                rewindSpeed: 600,
                pagination: true,
                navigation: false,
                autoPlay: true,
                singleItem: true
            });
        });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">.recent-posts .item .col-sm-5, .recent-posts .item .col-sm-7{width:100%;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#latest_news .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                lazyLoad: true,
                responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
                slideSpeed: 200,
                paginationSpeed: 500,
                scrollPerPage: true,
                stopOnHover: true,
                rewindNav: true,
                rewindSpeed: 600,
                pagination: true,
                navigation: false,
                autoPlay: true,
                singleItem: true
            });
        });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="padding:0 10px;">
        <div class="single-images">
            <div class="row" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/brochure-and-booklet-printing.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Brochure Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/brochure-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Brochure &amp; Booklet Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/business-card-printing.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Business Card Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/business-card-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Business Card Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/folded-leaflet-printing.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Leaflet Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/folded-leaflet-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Folded Leaflet Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
            </div><br>
               <div class="row" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/flyer-printing.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Flyer Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/flyer-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Flyer Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/tickets.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Ticket Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/ticket-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Ticket Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a class="image-link border-radius" href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/business-stationary-printing.html"><img style="width: 100%;" title="Business Stationary Printing" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/content/06/business-stationary-printing.jpg"}}" alt="Business Stationary Printing" width="269" height="199" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="shop-features"><h2 class="shop-features-title"><span>Low Cost Leaflets, Flyers &amp; Business Cards in Lincolnshire &amp; throughout the UK</span></h2>
</div>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: small;">Working in partnership with some of the largest &amp; best national printing companies allows us to offer our customers top quality digital &amp; lithographic printing at lower prices.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: small;">We&rsquo;re not just here to provide you with quality promotional material but work with you to bring you quality products that reflect well upon your business. So if you&rsquo;re having them delivered door to door, if they're going out with orders or if your print will be sitting in a reception area, you'll have the right product for the job.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: small;">Whatever you will be using your leaflets for we can suggest amounts, thickness, shape, size &amp; finish of your leaflets to make sure you get the results you need.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: small;">With offices in the centre of Lincoln, we are available weekdays 9am - 5pm to answer any questions &amp; give you any help you may need in choosing the print products which are right for your business.</span></p>

        <div class="shop-features">
            <h2 class="shop-features-title"><span>WHY SHOP WITH US?</span></h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <h3>Find Your Perfect Print Product</h3>
                    <p>We offer a wide range of printing services &amp; products.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/our-products">About Our Product Range &gt;</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="icon-reply"></i>
                    <h3>Order &amp; Make Payment</h3>
                    <p>Ordering is easy &amp; we accept many payment types.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/faq">Paying for your Order &gt;</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="icon-paper-plane"></i>
                    <h3>Receive Your Print Order</h3>
                    <p>We'll ship your order free to any UK mainland address.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/delivery-info">Delivery Information &gt;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to show 5 JPEGs, you will need 5 requests. This is not a big overhead and in contrast to small design elements, it doesn't make sense to put them into a sprite. Better pay attention to optimizing the size of the images.
2. You can use *protocol relative* URLs instead of adding "https://", i.e. "//www.lincoln-printing-services.co.uk/business-stationary-printing.html". But if these are links within your Magento instance, you should not write them by hand at all. Use one of those instead:

   - `<a href="{{store url="catalog/category/view" id="123"}}">...</a>` if it is a link to the category with ID 123 (`catalog/category/view` can be any route)
   - `<a href="{{store _direct="business-stationary-printing.html"}}">...</a>` if you want to specify the URL directly, independent of the route. This will basically prepend the base URL of the current store.